# Site gif delay/overlap

Tags: javascript, html, css, gif

The question title may not be very good but I don't really know how to describe it so here it goes:

I have N `<td>` elements with text (*text1, text2, text3...*) that when you hover over each of them a pop-up appears with the respective gif playing (*gif1, gif2, gif3...*). And when your mouse leaves the `<td>` the gif disappears.
My problem is this:

1. Hover over text 1--->  pop-up appears with gif1 playing [***correct***]
2. Leave text1----------->  pop-up disappears [***correct***]
3. Hover over text2---->   pop-up appears with **gif1** playing for a bit (0.5sec-1sec) and **then** gif2 plays [***incorrect***]
4. Leave text2----------->  pop-up disappears [***correct***]
5. Hover over text3---->   pop-up appears with **gif2** playing for a bit (0.5sec-1sec) and **then** gif3 plays [***incorrect***]

And on and on ([video example](https://youtu.be/T7V9ZpUmFbw)).

So how can I make it to not show the previous gif every-time the new one is supposed to play?

---

**HTML**

The pop-up is basically a `<div>`:

```
<div class="popup">
 <img class="myPopup">
</div>
```

**JS**

the `<td>` have a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` event that trigger the functions `pop_in` and `pop_out` respectively.

```
var popup_here

function pop_in(e){
    var row_num=.....//getting the coordinates
    var ex_num=.....//getting the coordinates

    popup_here=document.getElementsByClassName("myPopup")[0];
    popup_here.src=....//setting the source to the correct gif from a list of objects using the row_num and ex_num variables

    popup_here.style.visibility="visible";
}

function pop_out(e){
    popup_here.style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

**CSS**

No fancy CSS besides the fade-in. But anyway, I've tried removing it altogether and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that any new gif needs time to load and in that time the previous source is displayed.

The easiest solution is to set your `src` attribute to some placeholder in your `pop_out` function.

Comment: Now I feel bad. I kinda guessed that that might be the problem, that's why I also tried doing a `popup_here=null` at the end of the `pop_out` function. But it did nothing. 
Now I tried `popup_here.src=null;` and it did work.
I thought that just having `popup_here=null` would be enough so I didn't even tried the `.src` until now.
Thanks for the help